# Relative links with altered reference point

Tags: html, css

Hopefully a very quick and easy to answer question.  I'm writing a website which has a fixed header/navbar.  As part of the navbar, there are relative links to bookmarked sections of the main page (using [W3.CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/default.asp)):

```
<header class="w3-container w3-top w3-blue-grey"
            style="height:150px;">
        <div class="w3-row">
            <div class="w3-col"
                 style="width:75px;
                        height:75px;">
                <img    src="/images/BW_Logo.png"
                        alt="TIVA Calc"
                        style="width:75px; height:75px;">
            </div>
            <div class="w3-rest">
                <h2>TIVA Calculator</h2>
            </div>

        </div>
            <ul style="list-style-type:none;
                       margin:10;
                       padding:0">
                <li style="float:left;
                           text-align: center;">
                    <a href="#drugCalc"
                       style="display:block;
                              padding:8px;
                              text-decoration: none;">
                       Conc.</a>
                </li>
                <li style="float:left;
                           text-align: center;">
                    <a href="#heightCalc"
                       style="display:block;
                              padding:8px;
                              text-decoration: none;">Height</a>
                </li>
                <li style="float:left;
                           text-align: center;">
                    <a href="#weightCalc"
                       style="display:block;
                              padding:8px;
                              text-decoration: none;">Weight</a>
                </li>
                <li style="float:left;
                           text-align: center;">
                    <a href="#ageCalc"
                       style="display:block;
                              padding:8px;
                              text-decoration: none;">Age</a>
                </li>
                <li style="float:left;
                           text-align: center;">
                    <a href="#calcResults"
                       style="display:block;
                              padding:8px;
                              text-decoration: none;">Values</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
    </header>
```

The problem is that the fixed navbar lies on top of the Z-axis and the content below doesn't float properly.  To get around this, I've enclosed the content in an absolutely positioned container in order that the content at the top is displayed. (I initially tried adding a few `<br>` in to bring the top down, but thought a container would be a better solution.)

The options I can think of are:

- Somehow altering the `href=#foo` to point to somewhere `150px` above the actual section I'm linking to
- Changing the `href` to point to an element approx `150px` above the target
- Altering the `<header>` element in order that it doesn't lie on top of the remaining content

I can see problems with the first two, especially with regard to responsive design.  I have no idea how to make the last one work.

However, I'm running out of skill/knowledge!  I'm sure this has been dealt with fairly regularly.  Any ideas?

Comment: You omitted your CSS which is probably central to your question. Also please don't confuse the [W3](http://w3.org) with w3schools.com. The former is a reference, the latter is a joke.

Comment: Ah! I'm using W3 schools CSS (http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/default.asp).  I will try to collate the relevant parts of this if it's helpful.  I'm a wee bit dissatisfied with it to be honest and I'm probably going to switch to my own